# What does prepayment mean on booking.com?

Tags: booking.com

I booked a hotel through booking.com and it says a prepayment is required the day after I book the reservation but it doesn’t say for how much and doesn’t explain about it. If the prepayment is let’s say $100 and my total was $400 when I get to the hotel to check in will I be charged $400 or $300 since it already took $100 out my account?

Answer (score 17):

Usually, if nothing else is indicated, prepayment means a 100% prepayment.  If the total costs $400, the entire amount will be charged at the indicated date.  When you arrive at the hotel, there will be nothing more to pay except, if applicable, city tax and extras.  The city tax should normally be mentioned somewhere, possibly in a tiny smallprint.

Comment: +1 This would appear to correctly differentiate "prepayment" & "deposit", which would be a fraction of the total.